# Incorrect result in Bitwise operations

Tags: variables, storage, bitwise-operators

I'm doing a bitwise operations on 2 bytes in a buffer, then storing the result in a variable. However, I sometimes get a non-zero value for the variable even though I'm expecting a zero value.

I'm sorry for not being able to post the whole code, but the code is too long for me to do that.

The relevant portion of the code is as follows.

```
unsigned int result = 0;
long j = 0, length;
unsigned char *data;

data = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*800000);
// populate data[]
while (j < length)
{
    result = (unsigned int)(((data[j]^0xb6)<<8)|(data[j+1]^0xab));
    if (result > 0)
        ... 
    (j gets incremented here)
}
```

I'm expecting `result` to be zero when my `data[j]` and `data[j+1]` are 0xb6 and 0xab respectively, which is the case for most of the time. However, for certain values of `j`, my `result` is strangely not zero.

```
j = 62910, result = 64
j = 78670, result = 64
j = 100594, result = 64
j = 165658, result = 512
j = 247990, result = 128
j = 268330, result = 512
j = 326754, result = 1
j = 415874, result = 256
j = 456654, result = 1024
j = 477366, result = 512
```

It appears that these strange `result` values are all powers of 2, with a 1 bit appearing somewhere in the `unsigned int`.

I'm not changing the value of `result` anywhere else in the code, and when I print out `(unsigned int)(((data[j]^0xb6)<<8)|(data[j+1]^0xab))`, I get `0`, but somehow when it gets stored in `result`, it's no longer zero.

I really don't understand what could be wrong.

Comment: Why not set a conditional breakpoint for one of the failing cases and see what's really going on ? Otherwise we can only guess...

Comment: What should I look out for at the breakpoint?

Comment: When you hit the conditional breakpoint then look at `data[j]` and `data[j+1]`, check to see that the values are as expected, then evaluate `(data[j]^0xb6)<<8`, `(data[j+1]^0xab)` and the complete expression `(((data[j]^0xb6)<<8)|(data[j+1]^0xab))` - it should be immediately obvious what the problem is, but even if it isn't you will have a lot more clues to work with.